# How to get non-null data out of Intent on file selection?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, xamarin.android

I would like to let user select an audio file, and then I would like to get the file path of it. However I have even simpler problem, because `Uri` of the intent I get is null. How I could get something meaningful, i.e. non-null?

Starting intent:

```
    private void MainActivity_Click1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //var intent = new Intent();
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, Android.Provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri);

        intent.SetType("audio/*");
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(
            Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select audio file"), SelectAudioCode);
    }
```

And responding to the selection:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode==SelectAudioCode)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Intent.Data;
            audioFileNameText.Text = uri == null ? "<NULL>" : uri.ToString();
        }
    }
```

No matter how I create the `intent` (see the code above), I see always `NULL`.

**Update**: if I use the `Intent` passed via parameter, the `Data` property of it is `null` as well.

Comment: did you get some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to let user select an audio file, and then I would like to get the file path of it. However I have even simpler problem, because Uri of the intent I get is null.

You can get the content Uri from `data.Data`. But if you want to get the file path out of content uri, you need to convert the content uri into real path:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    string abc= getRealPathFromURI(this,data.Data);
}


public string getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri)
{
    ICursor cursor = null;
    try
    {
        string[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.Data};
        cursor = ContentResolver.Query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        return cursor.GetString(column_index);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Explaination Update:

The intent you are currently using by `Intent.Data` is the intent that start current activity, not the intent that chooser returned back:

[image]

So instead of using `Intent.Data` you need to use the `intent` returned by the chooser activity, which is `data` argument:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote -- "I have simpler problem, the Uri is null". I.e. as you wrote "You can get the content Uri from data.Data", it is further step for me, because `data.Data` is `null` I cannot process it at all.

Comment: The Intent you are using is the Intent that start the current activity, But you can only get the Uri from the Intent returned by the Chooser. @greenoldman sorry for not clarify that clearly, I have update my answer to clarify the difference between Intent of current activity and the Intent in the `OnActivityResult`.

Comment: Thank you, I will update my question as well, I checked that `Intent` as well. The data of it is also null :-(

Comment: I'm not having null from `data.Data`. You can have try of my [demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/EmptyIntentDemo). If the problem persists, could you offer a detailed steps of reproducing the problem?

Comment: Weird things. I switched the way I create intent (the first two lines) and it worked (with intent from the parameter)! So to be sure I switched them back and... they worked again. Nevertheless I am pretty happy and thank you for your help.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT did you get some solution?

Comment: @Clystian I believe the answer I provided is a solution to this problem. Please read through the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Xamarin. The Java equivalent of what you are trying to achieve is this.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setType("audio/*");

this.startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_CODE);
```

Comment: Thank you, but what `file` should be? I am about to ask user to select the file, so I don't know in advance what she/he will select.